# Google analytics doesn't show the stats

Tags: google-analytics

I have added the google analytics code to my homepage, but I don't see any visit statistic. I tried refreshing the page from many places, but in my google analytics account the number of visits is still zero. I put the code in my page's head tag.

Is there any common mistake that I may have or any potential problem with the page (http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~u5410055/)?

Comment: It takes around 24 hrs to reflect the data in Google analytics.

Comment: Also check your real time reports to see if you can see your own visits.

Comment: @SiddharthVyas I waited for another 24 hours and it is solved now.